# memory size of database and tables

Tags: mysql, database, memory

I am new to the MySQL learning. I have a database that consist of 34 tables. I just want to know the memory size of database and each tables. Is there any special query or script to finding the memory size? please help me out with this. am using InnoDB engine.

Answer (score 1):

For DB

```
 SELECT table_schema AS "Database", 
 ROUND(SUM(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 2) AS "Size (MB)" 
 FROM information_schema.TABLES 
 GROUP BY table_schema;
```

For table

```
SELECT table_name AS "Table",
ROUND(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) AS "Size (MB)"
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE table_schema = "database_name"
ORDER BY (data_length + index_length) DESC;
```

Comment: for DB is working perfect. can you check the query for table, its hitting ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'cpstoptransaction' in 'field list'

Comment: It clearly says unknown column which you have created. So you give it a look or post your query and table structure.

Comment: Let me know if you get the result.